# Getting JSON data using Google Books API on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am getting JSON information from Google Books. When user types book title, recommendations from Google Books are loaded as a list. If user clicks on the recommended title, this value will be put in the input field and by submit button click title is inserted into the database. But there is also additional information on the clicked book, that I need to get but it must not be shown (so I cannot get it using using `.val()` ). So I need to get `item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[1].type` of the clicked element just as variable. How can I implement this?

```
    var request = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes';
    $('#myTextArea').on('keyup', function(){
        var keywords = $(this).val();
        if(keywords.length > 0 ){
              $.getJSON(request + '?q=' + keywords, function(response){

        for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
            var item = response.items[i];


document.getElementById("outputdiv").innerHTML += "<br>" + "<div class='itembook' >" + item.volumeInfo.title + "</div>" ;

     $(".itembook").click(function(){
             $('#myTextArea').val('');
             var itemsc = $(this).text();
             $('#myTextArea').val($('#myTextArea').val() + itemsc);

            });

          }
          });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of what are you asking really for :( coudl you help with a clearer description

If the user clicks a book, and you need to get a specific value of the json received , in the moment of the rendering (for) :

```
//save it in the DOM object with a "data" html attribute.
document.getElementById("outputdiv").innerHTML += "<br>" + "<div    class='itembook' data-type='"+ item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[1].type +"' >" + item.volumeInfo.title + "</div>" ;
```

then in your click event , you can define :

```
var type = $(this).data("type");
```

that way the value will be hidden but you still can get the value of the book.´

Did i misunderstood the question ? if so sorry.

Comment: You understood it absolutely right in spite of mistakes in the question)

Comment: @Vinand to be more accurate also check item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers array sometimes type is not give ... solution is correct though

Comment: Super :)  (i just comment to win a badge haha)

Comment: @CarlosDelgado And what if I need to get two variables instead of one data-type?

Comment: Well you can simply add another data-* attribute for example :  data-batman="other value" , you can give al the data attributes that you want if they are different. You can too , have only 1 data attribute with a Json within, like : data-book="{"book":{"name":"metro2033"}}" and retrieve the complete object when you need it , using JSON.stringify when you need to pass an array to string and JSON.parse to make it object when you retrieve it from the data tag :) Just like facebook does